# Mailkit Email not showing as clickable link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mailkit

I am trying to send a confirmation email and everything is working except that the link comes through as plain text and not as a clickable link.

This is my code:

```
        public static Task SendEmailConfirmationAsync(this IEmailSender emailSender, string email, string link)
    {
        return emailSender.SendEmailAsync(email, "Please Confirm your email",
            $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{link}'>link</a>");
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of email link]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is your email client set to display emails as plain text by default?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Let me check now

Comment: I am sending my emails through my shared hosting account and in the Plesk email settings there is no option to change from plain text to HTML

Comment: Not sure how to help you as this isn't a coding issue. The email is clearly being displayed as plain text or you wouldn't see that HTML anchor tag.

Comment: Fair. I suppose I will contact support.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the code in MessageServices.cs also.  Are you setting body to `new TextPart("html") { Text = message }`?

Comment: Please share the code for `SendEmailAsync`.

Comment: Add true for html type:
EmailService.Send(user.Email, "Reset Password", $"Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>",true)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check that whatever email client you are using is displaying the email as HTML. It appears from your screenshot that the email is being displayed in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

using NETCore.MailKit.Core;

Add true for html type:
EmailService.Send(user.Email, "Reset Password", $"Please reset your password by clicking here: link",true)

Answer (score 0):

you must sent us mail template. how are you writing on html page this code.
get link only like string and create a mail template and in a tag write like  `MailText = MailText.Replace("[FirstName]", user.FirstName).Replace("[email]", user.Email).Replace("[URL]", URL)` and in html you must write  `<a href="[URL]">Click Here</a>`